# How to attach and send a user selected local file for email attachment in a web app

Tags: javascript, meteor

If you were building a web app, and you wanted to allow the user to attach a file to send in an email (as an attachment), how would you do it? In my case, in Meteor, I'm able to do this successfully but only if the path is hard coded into the attachment object:

```
Email.send({
...//some code here
...
To: "johndoe@email.com",
From: "janedoe@email.com",
Subject: "Subject Title",
Text: "Compose email text",
attachment: [{ filePath: "/Full/Path/To/filename.txt"}]
...
}]
```

It appears the best the browser can do is get the file name and that's it. So how could the user select a file to send if the browser doesn't have access to the file system? Am I out of luck? Maybe I'm not thinking outside the box enough.

Comment: you can always upload the image to a server (with input upload) and provide a link inside the email message body....

Comment: True. Perhaps email attachments are passé these days. Just link it.

Comment: the problem is with the file api of html5 which is very problematic and does not support that feature... because it's a web app we are very limited with what we can do